# does MSI installation has power to skip the installation of dependent software?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

The issue is because of MSI. in MSI we can't able to check the version of dependent application which installs as a part of installation.

in exe we can check if the higher of software already exist it uses that and skip's the current one (which is trying to install) and proceed with next step of installation.

but where as in MSI it doesn't skip if the application already installed (specifically if it exist in higher version than the MSI has)

the given points about working of MSI are correct?
if it is, how can make the installation success in such cases ?

the given points about working of MSI are correct?
if it is, how can make the installation success in such cases ?